# bridge club alert rules internationally

Tags: bridge, duplicate-bridge

Are the rules for alerting bids broadly similar at clubs throughout the world, or do they differ? Are bidding boxes used internationally?

(My most specific interest is whether clubs in Switzerland are like clubs in the US but I have asked the question more generally because it may be of use to others. Of course I will ask the local director when specific questions arise, but there is a language barrier, and the director here may not know what I am accustomed to in US clubs, so I hoped someone here could offer a comparison.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have played extensively in clubs in the US and Switzerland, and occasionally in other countries. Bidding boxes are now in almost universal use. Alert rules vary by country, and are substantially different from what you are used to in the ACBL. Fortunately most are simpler than the ACBL's. The club directors I met in Switzerland spoke excellent English -- I recommend asking. Be sure to inquire about Stop Card use as well.

The Swiss Bridge Federation (FSB) site is http://www.swiss-bridge.ch/ but I did not spot anything about alert rules.

Comment: This is consistent with my experience also.